# getting the inverse of each element and putting it in array in python

Tags: python, sage

guys i am totally new to programming so i want your help. i want to make a function that takes a 2 dimensional array and maps each non zero element to it's inverse and putting it in `new_arr` but it doesn't give me what I need 
here is my code:

```
def question(arr):    
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            z = arr[i][j]
            new_arr[i][j] = z^-1
    return new_arr[i][j]

question([[70,52,13,67],[90,48,57,26],[43,45,67,89],[88,65,44,23]])
```

so any help please ?

Comment: Please check your indentation! Was it lost due to copy and paste?

Comment: @noazet `^` is the bitwise `xor` operator and not the power operator. You can use `**` operator as the power operator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR

Comment: [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) uses Python with some additional syntactic sugar.  So `^` is in fact exponentiation (and `^^` is xor) in this context.  I like the list comprehension method below myself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to solve this problem

```
def question(arr):
    return [[1.0/col if col else col for col in row] for row in arr]

print question([[70,52,13,67],[90,48,57,26],[43,45,67,89],[88,65,44,23]])
```

To do this in your way

```
def question(arr):
    new_arr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        row_arr = []
        for j in range(len(arr[i])):
            row_arr.append(arr[i][j] ** -1)
        new_arr.append(row_arr)
    return new_arr

print question([[70,52,13,67],[90,48,57,26],[43,45,67,89],[88,65,44,23]])
```

You have to create a new list for every row and append it to the result. BTW, `^` refers to bitwise exclusive OR in python. So, you might want to use either `1.0/x` form or `x**-1` form. `**` refers to power, in python.

Comment: i can't get this line well "col if col else col for col in row] for row in arr"

Comment: @noazetabdo updated with your modified code now. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/) and a value of inf is acceptable for any items that are 0 then:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[70,52,13,67],[90,48,57,26],[43,45,67,89],[88,65,44,0]],
              dtype = np.float32)

>>> 
>>> 1/a
array([[ 0.01428571,  0.01923077,  0.07692308,  0.01492537],
       [ 0.01111111,  0.02083333,  0.01754386,  0.03846154],
       [ 0.02325581,  0.02222222,  0.01492537,  0.01123596],
       [ 0.01136364,  0.01538462,  0.02272727,         inf]], dtype=float32)
>>> a**-1
array([[ 0.01428571,  0.01923077,  0.07692308,  0.01492537],
       [ 0.01111111,  0.02083333,  0.01754386,  0.03846154],
       [ 0.02325581,  0.02222222,  0.01492537,  0.01123596],
       [ 0.01136364,  0.01538462,  0.02272727,         inf]], dtype=float32)
>>> pow(a, -1)
array([[ 0.01428571,  0.01923077,  0.07692308,  0.01492537],
       [ 0.01111111,  0.02083333,  0.01754386,  0.03846154],
       [ 0.02325581,  0.02222222,  0.01492537,  0.01123596],
       [ 0.01136364,  0.01538462,  0.02272727,         inf]], dtype=float32)
>>>
>>> inverse_of_a = 1/a
>>> inverse_of_a
array([[ 0.01428571,  0.01923077,  0.07692308,  0.01492537],
       [ 0.01111111,  0.02083333,  0.01754386,  0.03846154],
       [ 0.02325581,  0.02222222,  0.01492537,  0.01123596],
       [ 0.01136364,  0.01538462,  0.02272727,         inf]], dtype=float32)
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want Python to compute "z^-1", you have to use the math module.
The math module has a function, pow, that takes two arguments, and returns base^power.
Here's a [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pow) to the documentation for pow.

You should replace "z^-1" with "math.pow(z, -1)" and place "import math" at the top.

Comment: `^` is bitwise `xor`, `**` is pow operator in Python.